# Colimits of cofibrations and homotopy colimits

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Say C is a left proper model structure. I have a diagram where all maps are cofibrations. Is its colimit a homotopy colimit?

I know this is true for pushouts. Is it true for sequential colimits? Filtered colimits? Sifted colimits? I am most interested in the sequential case.

This question is obviously related to, and is a slight generalization of, [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235526/when-do-colimits-agree-with-homotopy-colimits).

Comment: This topic was discussed here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/70612/when-are-diagrams-of-cofibrations-projectively-cofibrant

Answer (score 8):

In general, this is certainly not true. Take for example a space $X$ with an action by a group $G$. As a group acts by isomorphisms, it acts in particular by cofibrations. But the map $X/G \to X_{hG}\simeq EG \times_G X$ from the orbits to the homotopy orbits is usually not an equivalence if the action is not free.

A sequential colimit of cofibrations is always a homotopy colimit if the first object is cofibrant. This follows for example by the general theory of [Reedy model structures](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reedy+model+structure): In the Reedy model structure a sequential diagram as above is cofibrant. If your model category is left proper, you can indeed drop the assumption that the first object is cofibrant.

In general, if you have a direct diagram category $\mathcal{D}$ such that for every $X \in \mathcal{D}$ the category of $Y\neq X$ mapping to $X$ has a terminal object or is empty, then the colimit of every $\mathcal{D}$-shaped diagram of cofibrant objects and cofibrations is a homotopy colimit. This follows again by the Reedy model structure on $\mathcal{D}$-shaped diagrams (as the Latching objects are very easy to determine).